# Помощь с чтением и записью файлов в php

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Только дошёл до темы с файлами и не понимаю как это должно работать, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Задание следующее: "Пусть у вас есть файл, в котором записано некоторое число. Откройте этот файл, возведите число в квадрат и запишите обратно в файл."

Пытаюсь указать путь к файлу (слева видно, что файлы hw3.php и hw3.txt находятся в одной папке 1-reading-and-writing-a-file)

[image: Пытаюсь указать путь к файлу (слева видно, что файлы hw3.php и hw3.txt находятся в одной папке 1-reading-and-writing-a-file)]

при попытке запустить код в браузере c помощью расширения для vs code "PHP Server" получаю ошибку:

[image: при попытке запустить код в браузере c помощью расширения для vs code "PHP Server" получаю ошибку:]

на последнем скриншоте видно, что после работы кода в папке FILE-SYSTEM создаётся файл hw3.txt в нём записан "0"

[image: на последнем скриншоте видно, что после работы кода в папке FILE-SYSTEM создаётся файл hw3.txt в нём записан "0"]

Я только подступился к этой теме и пока совершенно не понимаю как это работает. Если можно, объясните простым языком.

Comment: простым языком: при первом запуске файла нет. Но вы не проверяете его наличие, в просто вызываете file_get_contents на строке 2, о чем вам и выдается предупреждение, что файла нет. Дальше - хуже. Эта функция при ошибке возвращает false (логическое значение). Затем вы false возводите в квадрат. Интерпретатор php преобразует false в число 0 и возводит в степень 2. Получается 0, вы пишите его в файл через file_get_contents. Далее до бесконечности можно читать этот файл и возводить 0 в квадрат - будет 0

Comment: @Дмитрий хмм, спасибо за ответ, но я всё равно не понимаю, ведь файл есть, вон он сразу под файлом hw3.php слева, я специально его для этого создал. Или дело в проверке? А как проверить наличие файла? У меня такое ощущение, что vs code не там его ищет, судя по тому, что он создаёт файл в папке уровнем выше (в FILE-SYSTEM, а не в 1-reading-and-writing-a-file в которой находится этот txt), но почему так - я не понимаю и что с этим делать.

Comment: окей, про пути.... Если вы гарантировано хотите работать с файлом в том же каталоге, где находиться ваш скрипт, то пишите file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/hw3.txt") и file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/hw3.txt", $num**2). __DIR__  возвращает директорию выполняемого скрипта. УУпс, В комментарии код преобразуется, смотреть тут  - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.magic.php

Comment: @Дмитрий Ура оно работает! Не сразу разобрался как прописывать этот DIR, но вот так всё получилось file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/hw3.txt"); (DIR надо обособить двумя нижними подчеркиваниями с каждой стороны) Это на будущее, вдруг кому понадобится. А вам спасибо огромное!

Comment: Маркдаун преобразует двойное нижнее подчеркивание в жирный шрифт:) Чтобы такого не происходило, ставьте апострофы по обеим сторонам: `__DIR__`

Comment: @AntonMironov спасибо, буду знать!